# convert MYSQL datetime value to UTC Timezone format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, timezone

New to MYSQL and java here. I am trying to convert a given datetime value being retrieved from a MYSQL database table with a request within a REST API application. The resulting json will display this and I found links where they mention Jackson Timezone formatting which sounds complicated .Isn't there a simple correct way to do this?

```
if(rs.getTimestamp(5) != null){
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(rs.getTimestamp(5).
    toLocalDateTime(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
pObject.setContractExpiration(zdt.get??????);
```

Found the above example but not sure what to put here zdt.get??????. My pObject class is expecting a Timestamp value. forgot to add, it has to be in this format:

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

Comment: do you get timezone in your sql timestamp as well?

Comment: No. The default format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and the MYSQL default is local time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
java.sql.Timestamp ts = resultSet.getTimestamp(PUBLISH_TIME);
cal.setTime(ts);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. Quick related question which came up while waiting. Can MYSQL support this format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'; ISO8601. Just thought it would be better to just keep the source the same if I can.

Comment: @vbNewbie - For the most part, dates and times don't have a "format" when stored in the database.  They are stored in a native binary form, and transmitted to the application layer in a similar binary form.  Formatting only applies when you emit the value as text in a string.